# Is it possible to share an excel file with multiple macros and vba code online without allowing the user to download the file?

Tags: excel, vba, collaborative

I have an Excel file that I use for thermal performance calculations, and it includes VBA scripts. I would like to share this file with my colleagues for collaborative purposes but would prefer to restrict their ability to download the file directly. Is there a secure and effective way to achieve this?

Thank you,

I have tried google sheets and MS OneDrive.

Comment: As far as I know macros don't work online so your colleagues won't be able to use them unless they download the file and execute it on local.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same obstacles a few years back in Google Sheets, the spreadsheet had a lot of Appscript codes that I didn't want anyone to copy.

**Please note this solution won't work if you uploaded an Excel with VBA as Google Spreadsheet uses different functions**

It would take lots of steps, so be patient.

I had to make a clone Spreadsheet with the data to be replaced with values only and another one with the formulas.

You should create a library on the main sheet to share your Appscript to the clone Spreadsheet.

This topic will guide you on how to do that.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/library

Once you've created and deployed the Script, move to the clone sheet and apply the library, it will show only the function name eg: (MyFunction ())

Based on the scripts/functions you have in the library, they can use it and apply it on the main sheet.

Copying the data into your main sheet is the easiest part, you could either do it with Appscript as well in various ways or you could use importrange function (I do not recommend it if the data is large)

Importrange function: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en
Sc